# Grade 12 chemistry question about Schrodinger's standing wave?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

this is my first time ever using a website like this but I have something I'm curious about. My chemistry teacher showed this today (img below) and discussed how quantum of energy that hits the electron has to be an integer otherwise decay occurs. What is stopping this from happening more often? Why aren't things decaying a lot and what are the factors to this?

[image]

Comment: Good question, at the start of quantum mechanics Bohr had the same question, 'why have'n't all electrons in atoms crashed into the nucleus',  and to fit the experimental data he had to postulate that no decay can occur. This is a huge difference between quantum and classical behaviour. Quantum mechanics is based on postulates such as this- but amazingly it always works- no error has yet been found. 'This is the way' to quote the Mandalorian!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: prophyrin, do you know why no decay occurs howverr and why only a integer is consumed? could it be related to the compton effect?

Comment: No not related to Compton effect. It is a postulate, we accept it (and Quantum Theory) because by doing so we find that we can explain all experimental observations made so far.

Comment: I see that makes a lot more sense thank you, it seems you and maurices answers are very different though. He answered how an electron falling into the nucleus would not decay the atom. You state it's impossible, can you give me some clarification on whether you're right, he's right or you're both somehow right?

Comment: You should probably try to find an into to Quantum theory something that explains a bit of history and principles without much math. Try 'Introducing Quantum Theory' by J. McEvoy & Oscar Zarate, publ Totem books in the US/ Icon Books in the UK.

Comment: Do you know examples that use math? I find that even if I can't understand everything, if i get the general idea, it would help me better understand. I will definitely look into the book, thank you for all your help :)

Comment: There are lots with maths, most any undergraduate physics or physical chemistry textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an electron "falls" on the nucleus, it cannot produce anything. The electron has not enough mass to produce a neutron, as the mass of the neutron is bigger than the sum of the masses of electron + proton. It is even not stupid to state that in a hydrogen atom, the electron has already fallen on the nucleus.

Comment: Maurice, wouldn't the electron shielding from an electron right beside the nucleus have negative effects?